# Scala Tutorial not rendered correctly in browser

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

After I created a new Play project (Scala), I navigated to `http://localhost:9000/@documentation/ScalaTodoList`.

Every single quote character on the page is rendered as 4 question marks,
so I assume there is some funny text encoding going on.

Since I am both a Scala and Play newbie, I have really no idea where to start looking.

Anyone who has a clue?

**Update**:

Same thing happens in both Chrome and Safari. I suspect it has something with the language locale the terminal window is configured to use (that runs the application at port 9000).

[image: safari / mac os x rendering characters wrong]

Comment: With no sample code we can only guess, and believe me that nobody likes it

Comment: It's a boilerplate project created with "play new foo". The documentation is the default/bundled one, as far as I can see.

Comment: I see, weird, repeated your steps with no problems. Is it happens also within your own views? Try on Play Google Group, maybe it can/should be considered as a bug.

Comment: Can you view the source and see if this is something your browser is doing?

Answer (score 0):

After I ran "locale", I found out that the locale was not set to an UTF-8 variant.

I shut down the process, and executed

> export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
>
> export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"

and re-ran "sbt run" -> refreshed the browser -> bingo.

Will have to remember to update my zsh profile.